Having trouble running a project locally/ npm install, dependency issues
I am trying to run an example project locally. Its a full stack project so it needs to access a mongodb database. I downloaded the project files, and ran npm install so I could get everything set up, but I think I've been running into dependency chaos...
I keep getting a bunch of errors when I try npm install
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: react-dom@16.14.0
npm error Found: react@15.7.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^15.0.0" from the root project
npm error   peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-bootstrap-table@4.3.1
npm error   node_modules/react-bootstrap-table
npm error     react-bootstrap-table@"^4.3.1" from the root project
npm error   2 more (react-modal, react-s-alert)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^16.14.0" from react-dom@16.14.0
npm error node_modules/react-dom
npm error   peer react-dom@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16 || ^17" from react-modal@3.14.4
npm error   node_modules/react-modal
npm error     react-modal@"^3.1.7" from react-bootstrap-table@4.3.1
npm error     node_modules/react-bootstrap-table
npm error       react-bootstrap-table@"^4.3.1" from the root project
npm error   peer react-dom@">=16.8" from react-router-dom@6.0.2
npm error   node_modules/react-router-dom
npm error     react-router-dom@"^6.0.2" from the root project
npm error   1 more (react-s-alert)
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   peer react@"^16.14.0" from react-dom@16.14.0
npm error   node_modules/react-dom
npm error     peer react-dom@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16 || ^17" from react-modal@3.14.4
npm error     node_modules/react-modal
npm error       react-modal@"^3.1.7" from react-bootstrap-table@4.3.1
npm error       node_modules/react-bootstrap-table
npm error         react-bootstrap-table@"^4.3.1" from the root project
npm error     peer react-dom@">=16.8" from react-router-dom@6.0.2
npm error     node_modules/react-router-dom
npm error       react-router-dom@"^6.0.2" from the root project
npm error     1 more (react-s-alert)
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\Tassneen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-18T19_49_34_347Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Tassneen\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-18T19_49_34_347Z-debug-0.log

I then tried it with --legacy peer deps and still got issues.
I also just tried running node index.js just to see what would happen and I got errors saying it doesn't recognize 'mongodb'??
<filelocation>node index.js
Connected successfully to db server
C:..\full-stack-banking-app-main\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:698
          throw error;
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'db')
    at C:\Users\Tassneen\Desktop\MITxPro\full-stack-banking-app-main\dal.js:12:17
    at C:\Users\Tassneen\Desktop\MITxPro\full-stack-banking-app-main\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:695:9
    at C:\Users\Tassneen\Desktop\MITxPro\full-stack-banking-app-main\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:285:23
    at C:\Users\Tassneen\Desktop\MITxPro\full-stack-banking-app-main\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:285:21
    at parseConnectionString (C:\Users\Tassneen\Desktop\MITxPro\full-stack-banking-app-main\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:580:12)
    at connect (C:\Users\Tassneen\Desktop\MITxPro\full-stack-banking-app-main\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:283:3)
    at C:\Users\Tassneen\Desktop\MITxPro\full-stack-banking-app-main\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:284:5
    at maybePromise (C:\Users\Tassneen\Desktop\MITxPro\full-stack-banking-app-main\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:692:3)
    at MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\Tassneen\Desktop\MITxPro\full-stack-banking-app-main\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:280:10)
    at MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\Tassneen\Desktop\MITxPro\full-stack-banking-app-main\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:426:22)

Node.js v20.12.1

I'm sure it was to do with dependency issues and/or outdated versions, but since I'm still very new to this, it's been really hard to debug and understand.
This is DAL script where it sets up the mongodb connection for reference:
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config();

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url         = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
let db            = null;
 
// connect to mongo
MongoClient.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err, client) {
    console.log("Connected successfully to db server");
    // connect to  database
    db = client.db('banking_app');
});

// create user account
function create(name, email, uid) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const collection = db.collection('users');
        const doc = {name, email, uid, balance: 0};
        collection.insertOne(doc, {w:1}, function(err, result) {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(doc);
        });    
    })
}

// find user account
function find(email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .find({email: email})
            .toArray(function(err, docs) {
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(docs);
        });    
    })
}

// find user account
function findOne(email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .findOne({email: email})
            .then((doc) => resolve(doc))
            .catch((err) => reject(err));    
    })
}

// update - deposit/withdraw amount
function update(email, amount) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')            
            .findOneAndUpdate(
                {email: email},
                { $inc: { balance: amount}},
                { returnOriginal: false },
                function (err, documents) {
                    err ? reject(err) : resolve(documents);
                }
            );            

    });    
}

// all users
function all() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
        const customers = db
            .collection('users')
            .find({})
            .toArray(function(err, docs) {
                err ? reject(err) : resolve(docs);
        });    
    })
}

module.exports = {create, findOne, find, update, all};


Is there a React version specified in the project's package.json? It looks like ^15.0.0 is specified but is not compatible with some of the dependencies. Try changing this to "react": "^16".
